# Please can I have examples of classical music vocal pieces for a trio

Tags: voice, classical-music, exam, audition

I am recently singing in a group consisting of me (a tenor), an alto and a soprano. We are looking for classical pieces to sing. I have searched the internet and cannot seem to find anything! Does anybody know of any or where I could find a list?

If not classical, then perhaps of the music theatre genre?

Answer (score 1):

[CPDL](http://cpdl.org) is your friend. Hit the "Multi-category sheet music search" on the front page. That will take you to a quite detailed search dialog where you can filter by several criteria, like period, voices, language, etc. etc. You will find tons of pieces, especially if you don't mind singing Renaissance songs (which CPDL seems to be particularly well stocked with).

Answer (score 1):

Another resource is [IMSLP](https://imslp.org). IMSLP hosts only music which is in the public domain. Its strength is music which is in the public domain because the composer died so long ago that copyright has expired. But there are also a few modern musical works whose composers have put them into the public domain.

IMSLP enables you to do detailed searches. For example, [here](https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:CategoryWalker/For_3_voices**Scores_featuring_the_soprano_voice**Scores_featuring_the_tenor_voice/) is the page you get to if you specify 3 voices, including soprano and tenor. Scroll down to see if any of the subcategories suit you. For example, under "Featured instruments" there is "Scores featuring the alto voice". If you click on the "show pages" link which is on the same line as a subcategory, IMSLP will give you a page of text links to its web pages for all the pieces of music IMSLP has, which match.